# Does L-Hopital's rule fail for $\lim _{x \to \infty} \frac{x+\sin x}{x+2 \sin x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

For $$\lim _{x \to \infty} \frac{x+\sin x}{x+2 \sin x}$$ if I solve it by dividing by $x$ and I get the correct answer which is $1$ but when I apply L-Hopital rule for $\infty /\infty$ form then I get answer as limit does not exist because we cannot say anything about $$\lim _{x \to \infty} \frac{1+\cos x}{1+2 \cos x}$$

Why does L-Hopital rule fail for this case? Or is something incorrect in my approach?

Comment: The second limit isn't any better because $\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos x$ doesn't exist.  Just because the L'H limit fails to exist doesn't mean the original did, too.

Comment: You don't need L'Hopitals rule for this limit.

Comment: This is an example where it is in fact **legal** to use L'H rule, it just doesn't help.

Comment: @MathOverview  ???? note that the limit is not at 0

Comment: how have you got $\frac{2}{3}$?

Comment: @Randall That is what I want to know. Why it doesn't help here? I understand that second limit does not exist but then shouldn't answer be limit does not exist ?

Comment: Because there is an actual theorem behind L'H rule.  It does not assert anything when the new limit fails to exist, because lots of things could happen.

Comment: In short, L'H does not say "whatever the new limit does, so does the old one."

Answer (score 11):

L'hopital says that if

$$\lim \frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{g^{\prime }(x)}$$ exists then 
$$\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ exists. In your case the first limit doesnt exist, this does not contradict the rule, but you cannot draw any conclusion about the second limit.

Comment: Thank you for succinctly saying what I was attempting to.

Comment: May you please explain the last statement ?

Comment: You have $P\to Q$ but $P$ is false. What can you conclude ? Nothing.